# Wrong link position when using the landscape environment

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, anchor

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{danish}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\begin{landscape}
\section{Title}
\subsection{Subtitle}
Here should be a rotated page with a drawing.
\end{landscape}

A

\end{document}
```

When I compile using `lualatex` and click any of the two entries in the ToC, I get to the bottom of the rotated page instead of the top where the (sub)section title is.

**Question**

How do I get the clickable link in the ToC to point to the top of the second page and not the bottom of the second page?

**My one suspection**

I think it might have something to do with a pageanchor, but I'm not sure at all.

Comment: works ok for me. Which pdf viewer do you use? Is your tex system up-to-date?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Hmm! I use Evince with an up-to-date Tex Live 2022 distribution on Fedora 36, but when I use Adobe Read 9.5.5 everything is fine. Thank you for locating the problem. (Should I delete the question?)

Comment: If you write an answer to my question, I can accept it and close the question.

Comment: you can answer yourself, you know which viewer didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ulrike guessed, the problem is do to the wrong PDF viewer; when using [Adobe Acrobat](https://www.adobe.com/acrobat.html) instead of [Evince](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince), everything is fine.

Comment: I'm part of the Evince dev team, if you can send me the PDF I could investigate the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @Nelson I've uploadet the file to https://file.io/BQh8kiTsCDva.

Comment: The link says the transfer has been deleted.